# Are there land animals that use gill-like organs instead of lungs?

Tags: zoology, respiration, breathing, lungs

Among aquatic, water-breathing animals, gills and other continuous-flow breathing methods dominate over lungs and other storage-based breathing methods as in land animals. Notably, axolotls have gill-like structures around their heads which use a high surface-area structure heavily vascularized with capillaries to breathe water.

However, it seems all air-breathing organisms use storage-based breathing, air-breathing fish included, as lungfish use their swim bladders as lungs, a clear example of storage-based breathing.

**Are there any land organisms that use continuous-flow breathing methods over lungs?**

Comment: That emphasizes that fish with only gills would have had much difficulty in adapting to land for the same reason that electric tyre pumps and manual tyre pumps are different.

Answer (score 9):

[Terrestrial crustaceans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Terrestrial_crustaceans) are land animals that use gills (or gill-like structures) for gas exchange, though these gills must be kept moist for efficient respiration.

Specifically, animals like hermit crabs have a [branchiostegal lung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branchiostegal_lung) that looks like gill tissue but is better adapted for absorption of oxygen from air instead of water.

Answer (score 8):

Some terrestrial hermit crabs (genus [*Coenobita*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coenobita)) have gills, but these are only partially responsible for their respiration<sup>1</sup>. These animals carry around water with them in the snail shell they 'wear'.

Amphibious land snails in the genus [*Pomatiopsis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomatiopsis) have gills<sup>2</sup>.

Finally, a terrestrial amphipod known as a "sand hopper" [*Talitrus saltator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talitrus_saltator) also has gills<sup>3</sup>.

### References:

1: [Farrelly, C. A., & Greenaway, P. (2005). The morphology and vasculature of the respiratory organs of terrestrial hermit crabs (Coenobita and Birgus): gills, branchiostegal lungs and abdominal lungs. Arthropod Structure & Development, 34(1), 63-87.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Peter_Greenaway/publication/229323552_The_morphology_and_vasculature_of_the_respiratory_organs_of_terrestrial_hermit_crabs_Coenobita_and_Birgus_Gills_branchiostegal_lungs_and_abdominal_lungs/links/5ac3f3830f7e9becc9d49554/The-morphology-and-vasculature-of-the-respiratory-organs-of-terrestrial-hermit-crabs-Coenobita-and-Birgus-Gills-branchiostegal-lungs-and-abdominal-lungs.pdf)

2: [Burch, J. B., & Van Devender, A. S. (1980). Identification of eastern North American land snails: The Prosobranchia, Opisthobranchia and Pulmonata (Actophila). Museum of Zoology and Department of Ecology and Evolutionary Biology, The University of Michigan.](https://molluskconservation.org/PUBLICATIONS/WALKERANA/Vol1/walkerana%20vol1%20no2%2033-80.PDF)

3: [Ungherese, G., Mengoni, A., Somigli, S., Baroni, D., Focardi, S., & Ugolini, A. (2010). Relationship between heavy metals pollution and genetic diversity in Mediterranean populations of the sandhopper Talitrus saltator (Montagu)(Crustacea, Amphipoda). Environmental Pollution, 158(5), 1638-1643.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3926130/)

Answer (score 0):

Modern reptiles (including birds, but possibly excluding turtles) have a continuous flow system of lungs. In birds, the lungs have air pushed over their lungs by larg air-sacs, similarly to how water is pumped over gills by the mouth in fish